# getting certain values of the datasets under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to know the number of rows where the condition 'treatment' in 'group' column and, 'new_page' in 'landing_page' don't match, how can i get it ? [image]

Comment: Do you want to visualise or only count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not the most beautiful way but it is, for me at least, the most straight forward and easy to understand solution:

```
selection = df.loc[(df['group'] != 'treatment') & (df['landing_page'] != 'new_page')]
```

with df.loc you simply &-chain your conditions together as in normal python if conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this if the purpose is just to get the counts:

```
data.loc[data.group == 'treatment',:].groupby(['group','landing_page'], dropna=False).count()
```